# What is the minimum time needed to see SEO result?

Tags: seo

Usually how much time needed to wait before we can see the result of our SEO effort on a new website?

Comment: As the answers indicate, you need to specify the type of SEO effort you are talking about.

Comment: I know the question is not phrased very well, but I gather that he wants to know how long it will take for search engines to index his site and for it to perform as it should given it is a new site. If that is the case, it can easily take 30-60 days before any site even begins to settle into the search engine result pages (SERPs) and depending on the site and the activity, back links, etc., it can take as much as a year to properly find it's place in Google. Bing is a whole other matter.

Comment: 6 days to 6 months.

Answer (score 1):

There is no set amount of time for two reasons:

1. Google crawls sites at different rates. This very question was indexed immediately but a page on your website may not be re-crawled for weeks. Search engines cannot take on-page factors into account until they know about them. So if a page isn't crawled for weeks, it will take weeks for any changes you make to be known and factored into ranking calculations.
2. It's difficult to assess the impact of changes due to the multitude of other factors that affect rankings. There are hundreds of ranking signals and not all of them are on-site (meaning they are factors that occur off of your website). Positive changes you make can be offset by negative changes offsite (i.e. you lose an inbound link). Plus your competition is always in flux as well. So you may make positive SEO changes but they are offset by changes/gains made by your competition so nothing seems to happen.

Answer (score 0):

This is very broad. Some changes are done in a day, some after a few weeks. Depends on the subject, how important your site is, the changes you've made.

If by 'SEO changes' you means proper html, new text, better use of keywords, you might need to check out your competition. If they're very good, changes might be minimal and thus hard to detect even though they happend.

There is no exact answer, but I'd say 1 week is reasonable for changes to be noticed.